# "RNCSafeAreaView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I try to open a bundle, but when the android is running it shows the next message

> 2020-01-05 23:15:45.366 26210-26210/com.note.principal
>   W/.note.principa: Accessing hidden field
>   Landroid/view/View;->mAccessibilityDelegate:Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate;
>   (light greylist, reflection) 2020-01-05 23:15:45.470
>   26210-26242/com.note.principal E/ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation:
>   requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaView" was not found in the
>   UIManager.
>
> ```
> This error is located at:
>     in RNCSafeAreaView
>     in Unknown
>     in Unknown
>     in n
>     in Unknown
>     in Unknown
>     in C
>     in P
>     in u
>     in RCTView
>     in RCTView
>     in h 2020-01-05 23:15:45.494 26210-26242/com.note.principal E/ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent:
> ```
>
> "RNCSafeAreaView" was not found in the UIManager.
>
> ```
> This error is located at:
>     in P
>     in u
>     in RCTView
>     in RCTView
>     in h 2020-01-05 23:15:45.502 26210-26242/com.note.principal E/ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent:
> ```
>
> "RNCSafeAreaView" was not found in the UIManager.
>
> ```
> This error is located at:
>     in P
>     in u
>     in RCTView
>     in RCTView
>     in h 2020-01-05 23:15:45.794 26210-26244/com.note.principal E/unknown:ReactNative: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent:
> ```
>
> "RNCSafeAreaView" was not found in the UIManager.
>
> ```
> This error is located at:
>     in RNCSafeAreaView
>     in Unknown
>     in Unknown
>     in n
>     in Unknown
>     in Unknown
>     in C
>     in P
>     in u
>     in RCTView
>     in RCTView
>     in h, stack:
> exports@175:1634
> get@163:682
> Al@89:70673
> Ml@89:70108
> Ul@89:67144
> Ul@-1
> Pl@89:65839
> Pl@-1
> <unknown>@89:25495
> unstable_runWithPriority@168:3915
> sn@89:25442
> cn@89:25377
> kl@89:64831
> la@89:87813
> render@89:90592
> exports@342:541
> run@334:1305
> runApplication@334:2287
> value@25:3685
> <unknown>@25:841
> value@25:2939
> value@25:813
> value@-1 2020-01-05 23:15:45.832 26210-26244/com.note.principal E/unknown:ReactNative: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent:
> ```
>
> "RNCSafeAreaView" was not found in the UIManager.
>
> ```
> This error is located at:
>     in P
>     in u
>     in RCTView
>     in RCTView
>     in h, stack:
> exports@175:1634
> get@163:682
> Al@89:70673
> Ml@89:70108
> Ul@89:67144
> Ul@-1
> Pl@89:65839
> Pl@-1
> <unknown>@89:25495
> unstable_runWithPriority@168:3915
> sn@89:25442
> cn@89:25377
> kl@89:64831
> la@89:87813
> render@89:90592
> exports@342:541
> run@334:1305
> runApplication@334:2287
> value@25:3685
> <unknown>@25:841
> value@25:2939
> value@25:813
> value@-1 2020-01-05 23:15:45.856 26210-26244/com.note.principal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
> Process: com.note.principal, PID: 26210
> com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaView" was not found in
> ```
>
> the UIManager.
>
> ```
> This error is located at:
>     in P
>     in u
>     in RCTView
>     in RCTView
>     in h, stack:
> exports@175:1634
> get@163:682
> Al@89:70673
> Ml@89:70108
> Ul@89:67144
> Ul@-1
> Pl@89:65839
> Pl@-1
> <unknown>@89:25495
> unstable_runWithPriority@168:3915
> sn@89:25442
> cn@89:25377
> kl@89:64831
> la@89:87813
> render@89:90592
> exports@342:541
> run@334:1305
> runApplication@334:2287
> value@25:3685
> <unknown>@25:841
> value@25:2939
> value@25:813
> value@-1
>
>     at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:71)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:371)
>     at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:150)
>     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:26)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>     at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:225)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 2020-01-05 23:15:45.862 26210-26244/com.note.principal I/Process: Sending signal.
> ```
>
> PID: 26210 SIG: 9

The package of project is

```
{
  "name": "Notes",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "bundle_android": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform android --dev false --bundle-output ./bundles/android/index.android.bundle",
    "bundle_ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ./bundles/ios/main.jsbundle",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.2",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.7",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.6",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

The project of gradle

```
include ':app'
rootProject.name='Notes'


include ':hermes-engine'
project(':hermes-engine').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/')

include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')

include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')



// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}




apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

project.ext.react = [
        enableHermes: false,
]

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false)

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')

    if (enableHermes) {
        implementation project(':hermes-engine')
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

This is the code of activity

```
package com.note

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView
import com.facebook.react.common.LifecycleState
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage

class ReactActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {

    private val OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1

    private lateinit var mReactRootView: ReactRootView
    private lateinit var mReactInstanceManager: ReactInstanceManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        SoLoader.init(this, false)
        mReactRootView = ReactRootView(this)
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(application)
            .setCurrentActivity(this)
            .setApplication(application)
            .setBundleAssetName("aaaaaa.android.bundle")
            .addPackage(MainReactPackage())
            .addPackage(RNGestureHandlerPackage())
            .addPackage(LinearGradientPackage())
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build()
        // The string here (e.g. "MyReactNativeApp") has to match
        // the string in AppRegistry.registerComponent() in index.js
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "Notes", null)

        setContentView(mReactRootView)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                val intent = Intent(
                        Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
                )
                startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                    // SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission not granted
                }
            }
        }
        mReactInstanceManager?.onActivityResult(this,requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

someone knows what is the solution?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I encountered the same error. In order to solve it make sure to install react-native-safe-area-context.

`npm install react-native-safe-area-context`

Then if you are using React Native 0.61.X make sure to do a `pod install`.
It will link everything together.

If you are using React Native < 0.6 then you need to do the linking manually with `react-native link react-native-safe-area-context`

Answer (score 3):

I was searched and found the next,

first, you need to clean the project

Second import modules at project

```
include ':app'
rootProject.name='Notes'


include ':hermes-engine'
project(':hermes-engine').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/')

include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')

include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')

include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')

include ':react-native-safe-area-context'
project(':react-native-safe-area-context').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context/android')

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-safe-area-context')

    if (enableHermes) {
        implementation project(':hermes-engine')
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}


 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        SoLoader.init(this, false)
        mReactRootView = ReactRootView(this)
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(application)
            .setCurrentActivity(this)
            .setApplication(application)
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .addPackage(MainReactPackage())
            .addPackage(RNGestureHandlerPackage())
            .addPackage(LinearGradientPackage())
            .addPackage(SafeAreaContextPackage())
            .addPackage(SDKCorePackage())
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build()
        // The string here (e.g. "MyReactNativeApp") has to match
        // the string in AppRegistry.registerComponent() in index.js
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "Notes", null)

        setContentView(mReactRootView)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                val intent = Intent(
                        Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
                )
                startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE)
            }
        }
    }
```

i will hope that it will be useful, also this link helped me

[react-native-safe-area-context](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context)

Answer (score 3):

In case you are NOT using ReactRootView (integrating existing apps to react-native)...

You probably still need to add your package (packages which don't support autolinking yet, i.e., the new **safe-area-view**, for instance) to `MainApplication.java`:

```
android/app/src/main/.../MainApplication.java
```

On top, where imports are:

```
import com.th3rdwave.safeareacontext.SafeAreaContextPackage;
```

Add the SafeAreaContextPackage class to your list of exported packages.

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            /**other packages of yours**/
            new SafeAreaContextPackage()
    );
}
```

Comment: But the bundle is in react native, the activity does not have this override

Comment: Indeed, the Activity does not. 
The Application does: MainApplication(.java)|(.kt)

Comment: maybe, in my case, i need to add the library

Comment: Sure, I suppose you are integrating an existing native android app with a react-native project, right? In this case, you are following the official docs which teach us how to implement react-native on Activities without having React Application.

That might be inferred as I can see you are manually declaring `mReactInstanceManager` which would pretty much do same as React Application.

Comment: This is the idea, because the project of react native is only the bundle, then i have a application in android and ios. they are the container but the code and function is in react native

Comment: I can confirm that adding the packages helps -> I am using react native 0.62.2. in an existing app (+ react native running in a fragment instead of an activity) and for some reason when trying to use react navigation in an existing app, it would not do the automatic linking, so I had to add `RNGestureHandlerPackage()` and `SafeAreaContextPackage()` manually

Answer (score 3):

Below worked for me :

1. npm install react-native-safe-area-context
2. react-native link react-native-safe-area-context
3. List item
4. inside android gradlew clean
5. npm start
6. npm run android

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me for below version and on iOS

```
"react": "16.9.0",
 "react-native": "0.61.5",
```

Step to resolve

-Stop the current running Metro Bundler

-install pod for ios

-try re-run the application

Hope this will help !

Comment: Android, not iOS

Answer (score 0):

if you're using some of the libs above try to use the version below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "1.13.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
```

Then run npm update or delete the nodule_Modules then : expo start or npm start.

if not work, Try in the terminal:
expo r -c

if still not work:

I found that this error could occur if you have a version mismatch/ incompatibility.
Here are some things you can try:
Run expo upgrade to ensure that Expo and all packages are running on the latest version (in your project).
Also, try running this command again:
`expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`
After doing all that, re-start the dev process (i.e. re-run npm start)