# RNCSafareAreaView was not found in the UIManager

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a react-native application and I am getting the following problem.
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt9FK.jpg)

My dependencies are as follows

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.13",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "^0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.8",
    "react-navigation-stack": "2.0.15"
    },
```

My App.js

```
    const LoginStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Login: Login,
        // Register: RegisterScreen,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Login',
        headerMode: "none"
    }
)

const Navigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        LoginSwitch: LoginStack,
        AuthLoading: SplashScreen
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'LoginSwitch',
        headerMode: 'none'
    }
)

export default createAppContainer(Navigator)
```

My index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import SplashScreen from './src/utils/splashScreen'
import App from './src/App'

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

If I put the splash in initialRoute, it works, but if I put the login in, it doesn't work

screen Login

```
class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Text>Teste</Text>
                <Text>Teste</Text>
                <Text>Teste</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824985/invariant-violation-invariant-violation-requirenativecomponent-rncsafeareavi

Comment: All of these dependencies are installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Manual Linking by either of the below two steps. Go to your project folder and add this to your pod file..

```
pod 'react-native-safe-area-context', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context'

//Then Do this on the terminal
    cd ios/
    pod install
```

OR

```
react-native link react-native-safe-area-context
```

This would solve the issue